# InteractionRequest<Confirmation>: the focus stays on the clicked button

Tags: wpf, prism, confirmation

Would anybody know how do I give the focus to the Cancel button of a Prism InteractionRequest?

What happens at the moment, is that given you've pressed enter on a button in a main window and the InteractionRequestTrigger fired, if you press enter again, you are in trouble as the focus stayed on the parent window and InteractionRequestTrigger  fires a second time...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I should have marked my Popup as Focusable!

Answer (score 0):

Focus on **Confirmation** dialog should be set automatically after firing the **InteractionRequestTrigger**.

You may find helpful the following **State-Based Navigation Prism** Quickstart:

- [State-Based Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405495%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec7)

A `Raise()` method is invoked in the QuickStart for showing the **InteractionRequest's** dialog at **ChatViewModel's** `SendMessage()` method by setting the proper **ViewModel** *context* and its *callback*:

```
public IInteractionRequest SendMessageRequest
{
    get { return this.sendMessageRequest; }
}

public void SendMessage()
{
    var contact = this.CurrentContact;
    this.sendMessageRequest.Raise(
        new SendMessageViewModel(contact, this),
        sendMessage =>
        {
            if (sendMessage.Result.HasValue && sendMessage.Result.Value)
            {
                this.SendingMessage = true;

                this.chatService.SendMessage(
                    contact,
                    sendMessage.Message,
                    result =>
                    {
                        this.SendingMessage = false;
                    });
            }
        });
}
```

In addition, the `ChatView` detects the interaction request and the `PopupChildWindowAction` displays the `SendMessageChildWindow` pop-up window:

```
<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding SendMessageRequest}">
    <prism:PopupChildWindowAction>
        <prism:PopupChildWindowAction.ChildWindow>
            <vs:SendMessageChildWindow/>
        </prism:PopupChildWindowAction.ChildWindow>
    </prism:PopupChildWindowAction>
</prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

I hope this helps.